# react native user ID | unique-username-generator

Tags: react-native, javascript-objects, userid

i am using React Native
i just want generator user ID with name Like Instagram, Twitter, TikTok,
have you any Suggestion how it's possible?

i try [unique-username-generator](https://github.com/subhamg/unique-username-generator) but getting an Error of [const crypto = require("crypto");](https://github.com/subhamg/unique-username-generator/issues/5)

Answer (score 1):

Install crypto-js,

`npm i crypto-js`

`unique-username-generator` is using `crypto-js`